# oracle insert after updating x columns data of the selected data

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to achieve a functionality  in my project:
I have to select **`10` rows** from a table having `5` columns and then insert the data in same table after updating 2 columns of the data retrieved (from the select query) ...what query will do for achieving the same functionality.

example :(10 rows)
data in column1 is 'zz','zz','zz','zz','zz','zz','zz','zz','zz','zz'.
data in column2 is 'ClassA','ClassB','ClassC','ClassD','ClassE','ClassA','ClassB','ClassC','ClassD','ClassE'

INSERT INTO tableT (SELECT * FROM tableT (update column1='yy',column2=append '_tt' on the existing data in the rows column))

after firing query, we have **20 records**, 10 old and 10 new.
**10 new records data** will be 
column1 is 'yy','yy','yy','yy','yy','yy','yy','yy','yy','yy'
data in column2 is 'ClassA_tt','ClassB_tt','ClassC_tt','ClassD_tt','ClassE_tt','ClassA_tt','ClassB_tt','ClassC_tt','ClassD_tt','ClassE_tt'

and the data of other remaining 3 columns will be same

please guide me in framing the query

Comment: Can you make your question clearer? Anyway, you might want to use an INSERT ALL statement.

Comment: It would be a lot easier for us to undertand your requirement if you posted some sample data, showing the starting position and the desired outcome.

Comment: @APC please check the edited question, now it should make more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the size of your query and on the way you want data to be updated. But for your example you could use

```
insert into table (column1,column2)
select decode(column2,'1','yy','2','zz',null) col1, col2 from table;
```

**EDIT:**

After you changed your question I dont understand what you want to do at all. Please explain this:

> data in column2 is abc,bcd,dce,xyz,etc

because I dont get the pattern.

**EDIT 2:**

OK. Here we go:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name> (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 
FROM (
    select  'yy' as col1 , (col2 || '_tt') as col2,col3,col4,col5, rownum r_num 
    from <table_name>
) where r_num <= 10;
```

You didnt specify which 10 rows you want. This will select and change firs 10 rows returned by inner select query.

Comment: @GrzegorzWilczura calrification you asked. The inner query returns only 10 rows

Comment: @jain007 So basicly You didnt want specificly 10 rows. You wanted ALL Your rows (which just happened to be 10). This makes query much easier :)

Comment: @GrzegorzWilczura: I have removed my downvote, and I am sorry for yesterday. :)